# UIIMagePicker on iPad to view photoLibrary crash

Tags: ios

Im trying to get my imagePicker to load photos from my sourceLibrary. With the following code the app crashes with the following message  'Application tried to present modally an active controller'

```
-(void)viewPhotoLibrary{
NSLog(@"get photos");



UIImagePickerController  *imagePickerController =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];


    UIPopoverController  *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                   initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
    pop.delegate = self;
    [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];



    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:
     CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)
                           inView:self.view
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                        animated:YES];






    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
    [imagePickerController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

comment the code

```
[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[imagePickerController setDelegate:(id)self];
[imagePickerController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

or use this code

```
-(void)viewPhotoLibrary{
NSLog(@"get photos");

 UIImagePickerController  *imagePickerController =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];


  UIPopoverController  *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                               initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
  pop.delegate = self;
  [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];



  [pop presentPopoverFromRect:
   CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)
                       inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                    animated:YES];

      }
```

Comment: i had removed this code 
[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[imagePickerController setDelegate:(id)self];
[imagePickerController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
from you original code

Comment: image picker need popover to open in ipad. you can't present it.

Comment: @ok, so how do I present it ??

Comment: please look above function

Comment: app still crashes with the following message - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'